# Configuring the URL path for CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring-boot

A Repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "app/cities",collectionResourceRel = "app/cities")
public interface CityRepository extends CrudRepository<City, Integer> {
    List<City> findByName(@Param("name")  String name);
}
```

mapping in URL http://localhost:8080/cities.

How can I change this path to http://localhost:8080/api/cities.

The Annotation

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "app/cities",collectionResourceRel = "app/cities")
```

does not help.

Comment: are you including spring-boot-starter-data-rest?

Comment: @Amer Qarabsa
'<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>'